# Express '/' GET request fails, but '/' post, put, delete succeed

Tags: reactjs, express

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here so eyeballs or an idea on how to fix it would be appreciated

Express (4.17.1) + React (17.0.2)

This works fine:

```
router.get('/test', postListView)
router.post('/', postCreateView)
```

but this fails:

```
router.get('/', postListView)
```

Controllers:

```
const postListView = async (req, res) => {
    // No output from req.method when route is to '/'
    console.log(req.method)
    res.json({message: 'List View'})
}

const postCreateView = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.method)
    res.json({message: 'Create View'})
}
```

My POST request React call (works fine):

```
fetch(`/`,{
  method:'POST',
  headers:{
    'Content-type':'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({title:text.current.value})
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

GET request that fails:

```
fetch(`/`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

Error from GET request:

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I can open the GET request in the browser by going to express directly (localhost:5000).

React is going through a "proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:5000"

I think I'm missing something fundamental with GET requests here but I can't see it so any help or docs would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: What kind of an error you've seen ? Please check the browser network tab or console logs by opening dev tools. And then check if there're any error logs in your express application logs.

Comment: No Errors in the network tab and the only error I get is posted in the question "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0".  PostMan can hit the endpoint just fine on port 5000 (express) but this seems to be something within react not making it to the express through the proxy...maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `/test` as resource path for GET route. Better you use the same route to make the GET request from your react application.

```
fetch(`/test`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

For `/` path, you need to specify which method you're using since you're using same path for both GET and POST request methods.

```
fetch(`/`, { method:'GET' })
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

Comment: Going to '/test' DOES work and this is not the issue.  Going to '/' does NOT work...this is where the issue lies.

Comment: Can you check the updated answer

Comment: Generally with fetch if no method is applied, it defaults to GET, however I took the suggestion and forced it to be a GET request and it still fails.  The network tab shows that React isn't even going to the backend express server.  Somehow React is keeping the request to itself and not proxy'ing it back to express...not sure how to fix that without changing the actual URL (which I don't want to do even though it works)

Comment: Yep that's correct